# Ephesians 2: 1- in what way we are "dead" , the functional or relational death of spirit i?

Tags: ephesians, authorial-intent

Text: Eph. 2:1
"even when we were dead in our trespasses, made us alive together with Christ—by grace you have been saved"

Answer (score 1):

First, the Greek text is (NA28 etc) is:

καὶ ὑμᾶς ὄντας νεκροὺς τοῖς παραπτώμασιν καὶ ταῖς ἁμαρτίαις ὑμῶν,

This is quite reasonably rendered by (say) the ESV as: And you were dead in the trespasses and sins

Note that any notion of being made alive is absent from this verse.  It does appear in V5: even when we were dead in our trespasses, made us alive together with Christ—by grace you have been saved—

This is part of the NT teaching that it likens the old sinful way of life that is opposed to God and spiritual things as being dead.  "being made alive" is a way of expressing the start of person spiritual life, "being made alive in the spirit" as opposed to the life in the flesh. Rom 8:10, 11, 2 Cor 3:6.  Indeed, according to Jesus in John 5:24, our eternal life begins when we accept Jesus:

> Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever hears My word and believes Him who
>   sent Me has eternal life and will not come under judgment. Indeed, he
>   has crossed over from death to life.